# How to solve two threads and two instances of static variable scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, concurrency, thread-safety

In my spring project, in the `context.xml`, I have a bean defined for which I call the init method which creates an object `leaderSelector` which is static.

```
init() {
   leaderSelector= new customObject();
   leaderSelector.start();
}
```

The `leaderSelector.start()` modifies the property `hasLeadership` of the object to `true`.

The above init method is called whenever the server start-up.

I also have a task scheduler which calls a different method in the same class `callJobs()`where I am accessing the object `leaderSelector`'s property `hasLeaderShip` which is `false`.

```
callJobs() {
    if(leaderSelector.hasLeaderShip()) {
        //do some important stuff
    }
}
```

1.) The `init()` runs first and sets the `hasLeaderShip` property for the object `leaderSelector` to `true` in one thread.

2.)The task scheduler calls `callJobs()` afterwards(in a different thread) and when it accesses the object `leaderSelector`'s `hasLeaderShip` property, it is `false`.

The object `leaderSelector` is static. But two different instances of it are created. How should I get rid of the problem.

**Complete program**

```
public class LeaderSelection extends LeaderSelectorListenerAdapter {

    private static LeaderSelector leaderSelector;

    @Autowired
    private JobExecutionSender jobExecutionSender;

    CuratorFramework client;

    String path = "";

    String zookeeperAddress = "/locks";

    @Value("${cds.dl.timeout}")
    private int sessionTimeout;

    public LeaderSelection() {

    }

    private void start() {
        leaderSelector.start();
    }

    public void init() {
        client();
        leaderSelector = new LeaderSelector(client, zookeeperAddress, this);
        leaderSelector.requeue();
        start();
    }

    public void callJobs() {
        if (leaderSelector.hasLeadership()) {
            jobExecutionSender.sendJobExecutions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void takeLeadership(CuratorFramework client) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Has LeaderShip:" + leaderSelector.hasLeadership());
    }
}
```

Comment: An *object* is never static - a *variable* is. It's very important to differentiate between objects and variables. What memory barriers do you have between these operations? Any synchronized blocks etc?

Comment: Considering static object concept doesn't work for this scenario, what is the best way to access the same object in two different threads at different times?

Comment: "Static object" isn't a concept at all, but it sounds like it *should* work, if done properly - assuming both calls are using the same classloader. It would help if you could demonstrate this in a short but complete program, instead of just describing the code in words...

Comment: added the complete program

Comment: That's in no way a complete program. If someone takes your code and copies it into a new text file, even if they *do* have all the relevant jar files, will it compile and run? Nope... Not that I asked for your complete program - I asked for a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and that doesn't have to be your *original* code at all...

Answer (score 0):

Try

1) to synchronize the access to the methods that modify hasLeadership

2) transform your leaderSelector to a Singleton class. See: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html

Comment: This one is interesting. Will try out.

Answer (score 0):

You have no memory synchronization between the threads, so the JVM doesn't track the assignment. Make the variable `volatile`.